# Is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ also a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V = \{(a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n):a_i$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots, n\}$; so $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Is $V$ a vector space over the field of real numbers with the operations of coordinate-wise addition and multiplication?

Comment: You've defined $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. You can make it into a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ if you like if you just drop all the imaginary stuff.

Comment: Oh, sorry I accidentally copied the question incorrectly.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: The questions is supposed to say that "If V is a vector Space over R, then is V a vector space over C?

Comment: I intuitively think that this shouldnt be true since R is a subset of C, therefore its not necessary that if we have a vector space over R, it will also be a vector space over .

Comment: However, I don't know which one of the vector space axioms would not hold, so that I can prove that "If V is a vector Space over R, then is V a vector space over C"

Comment: The answer is no, because to be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, it must be closed under complex scalar multiplication, which it is not.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot Rotten for the help, I really appreciate your help